# How to localize existing content in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, generator

I have set up a simple Rails app based on Post, Comment example from the default documentation. -> http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

What would be the appropriate way of localizing existing content from these Posts ?

If I assume that Post has a :title and "content, and I would like this content to be entered not only in English, but also in German and Dutch, then how would I achieve this if I want the end result to look similar to this :

`http://0.0.0.0:3000/en/posts.json` to get all posts in English and respectively,
`http://0.0.0.0:3000/de/posts.json` for German?

I havent found a gem yet, that would support such multilangual content.

I have seen doe, many existing ways to do so, mostly in applications like Wordpress or Drupal, which are not rails based.

I guess the preferred way would be either storing EN and DE posts in seperate tables (but then how to add new languages?), or to place all translations within the same database table, but seperate translations in a different way, but how to get them easily out in json in the right language?

I am really confused and puzzled why such a "common" problem, is not solved in Rails by default, or maybe I am simply looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) will do what you want to do. It stores all translations for a particular model in a separate table, with a `locale` column identifying what the language of a particular translation is. This makes it possible to add new languages without having to migrate the database, so the approach is very scalable.

There are other gems for translating content as well, e.g. [Traco](https://github.com/barsoom/traco) is one that I know of, but this one stores the translations in the same table as the model, so when you add new languages you have to migrate each model table. I personally prefer the Globalize3 approach, although it makes the gem itself more complicated internally.

Comment: I looked into Globalize3 gem. It is not clear to me, how will it affect the forms, and how the language selection is happening during the runtime of the app. Maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: Language selection happens based on the `I18n.locale` and (optionally) `Globalize.locale` settings. If you set `I18n.locale` to say `:de`, then whenever you access an attribute on a model, say `post.title`, Globalize will intercept that and instead of looking for the `title` column in the `posts` table, it will look for it in the `post_translations` table (the table that Globalize3 creates for storing translations of a model). It will also add the current locale (`:de`) to the query when it searches that DB table, so that you get the `title` in German only. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes perfect sense, I was thinking more in lines of "How to change locale" from a view.?

Comment: If you mean display data in a particular locale, you can iterate over `Globalize.locale`, or better yet use `Globalize.with_locale(locale) do ...`. You can also iterate over a set of locales this way (usually set in e.g. `I18n.available_locales`).

Comment: If you mean forms, then it's just a matter of making sure that rails knows which locale the data is for, which is usually set with a query param (e.g. `param[:locale]`). It's somewhat more tricky if you want to update data for more than one language at a time.